# I Have a question about jquery performance

Tags: jquery

Will I have a performance problem if there are 500 elements with this class?

```
$('.class').hover(function handleIn() { /*code*/ },function handleOut() { /*code*/ });
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it give you any problems?

Comment: You should paste /*code*/, performance here is not clear.

Comment: Probably not, comments don't take long to execute. ;-)

Comment: Given the complete lack of detail (hardware/software/environment) in the question....

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the functions once outside the hover event. So they are created only once and not 500 times:

```
 function handleIn(){}
 function handleOut(){} 

$('.class').hover(handleIn,handleOut);
```

Comment: that makes no difference at all. Now there are 1000 anonymous functions which call another function and beyond that, calling it like this will still create 500/1000 unique event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of nodes with the classname `class` (you mentioned 500) jquery will bind 500 distinct event handler methods for each node. That of course is slower in comparison to only *one* event handler which handles all nodes.

That is the principle of *event delegation* and *event bubbling*. If there is a parent node which all of these `.class` nodes share, you can delegate any event to that parent node. Of course all elements share the `document.body`, so for demonstration it is:

```
$(document.body).delegate('.class', 'mouseenter', function(e) {
    // code when entering
}).delegate('.class', 'mouseleave', function(e) {
   // code when leaving
});
```

As mentioned, `document.body` can/should get replaced with a shared parent node which is closer to the nodes. You can also distinct between the hovered nodes in those delegated event handlers by checking the `event object` or `this`, both reference the current node if invocation.